# how does the assembler know which type of machine code to generate?

Tags: assembly, cpu-architecture, low-level

So I know that assemblers are basically programs that convert say C code to certain machine code that the CPU can understand. Now my question is, how does the assembler know what kind of machine code to generate that my CPU can understand. There are a million different types of CPUs with their own machine-specific instruction set, how does the assembler know which type it should generate. Apologies in advance for asking a stupid question like this but it's been bothering me for quite some time now.

Comment: You're always compiling / assembling for a specific ISA.  The C compiler knows what machine it's targeting, and runs an appropriate assembler if it doesn't have one built in (e.g. if it's GCC not clang).  A GCC cross-compiler needs a matching install of cross-binutils somewhere you tell GCC where to find it.

Comment: Assembly language is just as CPU-specific as machine language, it basically exists as a human-readable way to describe machine code, if that's what you were missing.  It knows either via command line options (`clang -target mips64 foo.s`) or directives (e.g. ARM `.thumb`), and/or because you ran a MIPS assembler vs. an x86 assembler like NASM.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, the assembler is going to be generating in a certain type of assembly language depending on the ISA, so if its an intel process for example the GCC compiler is just going to generate x86 assembly code as opposed to MIPS. Right?

Comment: Yes, unless of course you're running a cross-compiler.  You can use an x86 desktop to build MIPS executables, by installing a build of GCC configured to target MIPS.  But you'd always install that as `mips-linux-gcc` or something, not as `gcc`.  So yes, if you just run `gcc`, you'll be building for the host architecture, where options like `gcc -march=native` make sense (to enable any ISA extensions like AVX and FMA available on the CPU of the machine where GCC is running), instead of just `gcc -march=skylake` for example which would work even if compiling from a MIPS workstation.)

Comment: Tysm for your answer, it makes perfect sense and it's actually kind of a neat solution now that I think about it.

Comment: You are talking about a compiler, not an assembler to convert C code to machine instructions. The assembler 'only' does that last step converting the mnemonics into binary form. See the second paragraph of the introduction https://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMBackend.html describing backends for different architectures. And here for the target-independent code generator as intermediate step https://llvm.org/docs/CodeGenerator.html other compilers may translate directly into a specific architecture

Comment: Compilers and assemblers know what architecture they are for the same way processors know what architecture they are for -- their programming is made for that architecture.